# saving cls. files in different folder than .tex file

Tags: document-classes, warnings

Is it possible to use a document class from a different folder than the .tex-files?

My documentclass is used in more than 1 document. I want to use the document class for all of them.

In my document I use it like this:

```
 \documentclass[]{../0_CommonFiles/documentclass}
```

This produces the warning:

> You have requested document class´../0_CommonFiles/documentclass', but
> the document class provides `documentclass'

But everything works how it`s meant to be.

My Question: Any ideas how to get rid of the warning without installing it to the texmf tree? It shouldn´t be working only on my laptop.

Comment: `\documentclass{documentclass}` and put `documentclass.cls` in `~/texmf/tex/latex/myclass/` or some other directory in the input path

Comment: Besides following the texmf-standard as David comments, it may depend on your system. E.g. with MiKTeX under Windows I can start the MiKTeX Console, enter the directory at `Settings/Directory` and finally execute `Tasks/Refresh Filename Database`. After that a path inside the `\documentclass{..}` is not necessary: it knows where to find it (if I put it there).

Comment: As David Carlisle has suggested it is better to save custom classes and packages in `texmf` directory. To complement his comment you can follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138/140456) to do it.